# What is the dual tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Someone's comment in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77290/mount-the-documents-folder-on-a-different-partition-11-10-unity) led me to realize there's a [dual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual) tag.

This tag is pretty silly. It looks like most of the questions are about dual booting, but some of them are about dual monitors.

It seems that in nearly every case someone typed "dual boot" or "dual monitors" and that got separated into [dual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual) [boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot) or [dual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual) [monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/monitors).

Should this tag be about dual booting or dual monitors, and synomized with one of those tags? Or do we really need a tag for things that come in pairs?

Answer (score 2):

The description that comes up with the [privilege of retagging questions](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/retag-questions) notes that when mistakes are made when using tags, like using spaces instead of hyphens, we should retag them. I guess the newer users of the site do not know that a hyphen should be used instead of space for compound words. As such, I guess we should retag all of those questions with the right tag. In other words, questions with [dual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual) tag should be retagged with either [dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot) or [dual-monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitors).

Comment: Valid, but this doesn't really stop the problem. People can certainly retag these questions, but the tag will still get used incorrectly unless it's synomized with something else or banned.